# Clearing a list

Tags: python, memory-management, refactoring, list

I find it annoying that I can't clear a list. In this example:

```
a = []
a.append(1)
a.append(2)

a = []
```

The second time I initialize a to a blank list, it creates a new instance of a list, which is in a different place in memory, so I can't use it to reference the first, not to mention it's inefficient.

The only way I can see of retaining the same pointer is doing something like the following:

```
for i in range(len(a)):
    a.pop()
```

This seems pretty long-winded though, is there a better way of solving this?

Comment: Please expand on "which is in a different place in memory, so I can't use it to reference the first"  This makes very little sense in a Python context.  Maybe in C++, but not in Python.

Comment: I was merely pointing out that if I have a reference to this object from within another object, the 'new' a is now a different one to the first, so I can't use this same reference to modify the new a. Python still has the concept of pointers and memory management, it just hides it from you.

Comment: "the 'new' a is now a different one to the first" While absolutely true, I can't see a situation where this matters.  A more complete code example might help explain where this would actually matter.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

You are looking for:

```
del L[:]
```

Comment: Similarly, you can also do 
L[:] = []

Answer (score 4):

I'm not sure why you're worried about the fact that you're referencing a new, empty list in memory instead of the same "pointer".

Your other list is going to be collected sooner or later and one of the big perks about working in a high level, garbage-collected language is that you don't normally need to worry about stuff like this.

Comment: He may be holding a reference to the list in another part of the program that would need to know that the list is empty.

Comment: Maybe, but that's not what he asked.  He was worried instead about losing a pointer to that particular location in memory, which is a dubious concept in Python anyhow.

Comment: He later clarified it in a comment.

Answer (score 1):

***this can help you::)***

```
L[:] = []
```